# downloading event log file from apex code

Tags: event, code

Can we download the event log file directly from apex code.(i.e., without using rest explorer/webservices manually.Everything should be written in Apex code only).

Regards,
Sravika

Answer (score 1):

No the ApexLog body is only available through tooling api endpoints.
[APEXLOG object in APEX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexlog.htm) 
Still you are able to make a HTTP callout to tooling api endpoint [APEXLOG in Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexlog.htm).

```
Httprequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/sobjects/ApexLog/' + log_id + '/Body' );
req.setMethod('GET'); 
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId()); 
Http httpReq = new Http(); 
HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(req);
```

As the size of the log files are less than 2MB callouts should work fine.  Also you have to add your Salesforce instance URL to the remote site settings.